# Force sign-in OIDC middleware for .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

This seems really simple, but I think I am missing a small detail.

Is there a way to force the user to reauthenticate every time the browser is opened? I am seeing options for IsPersistent = false and I can set the ExpiresUTC to 10 seconds and it works, but I need this behavior to run whenever the user closes the browser or some other mechanism to force a login.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            options...
            options.Events.OnTicketReceived = c =>
            {
                c.Properties.IsPersistent = false;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = c =>
            {
                c.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        })
```

Thank you.

Comment: To have a session cookie, there should be no expiration set. What does the cookie look like in the browser with current settings?

Comment: Thank you Noah. The following cookies show Expires as Session: .ASpNetCore.Session (LAX), .AspNetCore.Cookies (Lax). My undertanding was that OIDC relies on ASP.Net session cookies. When I close the browser, Session isn't cleared. I ensure it gets called if the Sign out happens, though.

Comment: I thought session cookies were supposed to clear on browser close, but this may apparently depend on browser settings: https://textslashplain.com/2019/06/24/surprise-undead-session-cookies/

Comment: I did try adding my site to the Chrome setting "Always clear cookies when windows are closed" but it behaves the same.  If I close out of the browser and go back in, the cookie still shows in the list of browser cookies (before reopening the site). Opening the site, the cookie Value and Size are exactly the same even after closing everything out and going back in. :/